# predict system of circular reference equations

Tags: r, linear-regression

If I have the data frame `x`

```
x = data.frame(y1 = c(1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 0, NA), 
               y2 = c(2, 6, 9, 0, 1, 7, NA), 
               x1 = c(3, 5, -8, 2, 5, 11, 12), 
               x2 = c(0, 1, 2, 8, 0, 1, 12), 
               x3 = 1:7)
```

And found that the best regression for `y1` relies on `y2` and vis-versa such that:

```
fit1 = lm(y1 ~ y2 + x1, data = x[1:6, ])
fit2 = lm(y2 ~ y1 + x2 + x3, data = x[1:6, ])
```

How could I come up with a prediction for `y1` and `y2` for the 7th observation?

Comment: Based on the information you provide, it is not possible. The only difference between these two models are the assumptions regarding errors. Otherwise, they are identical.

Comment: edited after this comment so that the two models are no longer identical.

Comment: But they *should* be identical. If y2 = a * y1 + b * x1 + c * x2 then y1 = 1 / a * y2 - b / a * x1 - c / a * x2, disregarding error terms.

Comment: Could you use the method of "successive approximations" as Gauss originally did to find the orbit of Ceres? That is, an initial estimate of Y1 is used to calculate an estimate of Y2, that is used to refine the value of Y1, and that is used to refine the estimate of Y2, etc. etc. until there is no further refinement of the values? While Gauss calculated manually, this can be programmed - and hey, it worked for him! This could be worth a try.